# NuGet package only showing up as prerelease in TFS-managed feed

Tags: tfs, nuget, azure-artifacts

I'm using TFS 2017 to build and publish a NuGet package to an internal feed managed by TFS. Pushing to the feed succeeds, however the package is only listed as "prerelease" and not as stable although I promoted the package to a release view. How do I need to configure TFS to make the package show up as stable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that NuGet uses [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) to determine if a package is stable or in prerelease. In my case I used automatic build version as configured in the build activity which resulted in a version number like `1.0.0-ci-20180507-070157`. Since that string includes a SemVer prerelease identifier (`-ci-.....`), the package is not published as stable. I changed the version to one without prerelease indentifier (e.g. `1.0.0.1234`) and the package shows up as stable.

Comment: You can turn automatic versioning off and just provide this extra parameter on the PACK command. `Version=1.0.$(Build.BuildId)`